# Determine textNode at character number of paragraph ancestor

Tags: javascript, textselection

Let's say we have the following HTML:

```
<p>1234<strong>5678</strong>.</p>
```

Let's say that if we wanted to consider '234' a selection it's *relative index to the `p` parent element* would be 1-3 (using 0 as starting index).

How do I determine what node (e.g. the `textNode`) is at character index 7 of the paragraph?

The obvious answer is the `textNode` belonging to the `strong` element: how do I do that presuming the text is *no* selection (e.g. there is no `window.getSelection()`) to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to actually be a bit easier than I thought however it *may* have limitations (that others are welcomed to expand upon).

```
var tl = 0;//text length, increment per node's textContent.length
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)
{
 console.log(i+' = '+ac.childNodes[i].textContent.length);
 tl = (tl + element.childNodes[i].textContent.length);
}
```

So we can use `break` when the length is suddenly *equal to or greater than* whatever character index reference we're looking for.

There may be a complexity of multiple nested nodes such as a `em` element nested within a `strong` element to be considered which others are welcome to expand upon.